# Prove that $\iint_S \text{curl }\textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{S} = 0$ where $S$ is a sphere.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Prove without using the divergence theorem.

The proof using the divergence theorem is very obvious, but I need the proof which does not rely on the divergence theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cut the sphere in half and use Stokes' Theorem.

Comment: No need. Empty boundary.

Comment: How is using Stokes' any different from using the Divergence Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\nabla\times\vec{F}\cdot{\rm }{\rm d}\vec{\rm S} = \nabla\cdot\left(\vec{F}\times{\rm d}\vec{\rm S}\right)
$$